# need tuple not str for port scanner

Tags: python, port

ok so basically ive decided to try and build a basic port scanner. heres my code:

(theres more above this, but felt itd be far too much to paste in here)

```
##Print port menu
print "-"*60
print "Specify ports"
print "-"*60
print """
1)Use default list
2)Specify your own port list\n"""
print"-"*60
menu2=raw_input("Please choose an option\n")
##Define default port list
default_list="21, 22,23, 24, 25, 80, 110, 135, 139, 443, 445, 553, 3306, 3389, 8080"

##Set port list to default if option "1" is chosen
if menu2 == "1":
    port_list='default_list'

##Request user port list if option "2" is chosen
if menu2 == "2":
    port_list=raw_input("Please enter the ports you would like scanned.\neg. 22, 23\n")

print "Ok, here we go"

for i in str(port_list):
    connection = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    results = connection.connect_ex(ip + i)
```

Which looks alright to me, but when i run it i recieve an error "AF_INET address must be tuple, not str"  I'm not sure which part is the issue? is it my default port string thats throwing the error? or is it a problem in my ip address formatting?? ive tried a few of my devices ip addresses and always get the same error.

Comment: The part where you try to pass a string as an AF_INET address? That would be the `connect_ex` call. Have you looked up the documentation for that?

Comment: definately not enough i guess lol. I will do that now.

Comment: Ok that works now, but now im back to my orginal error, which is " connect_ex() takes exactly one argument (2 given)"  however i need it to be able to use the ip address and port, how can i combine this into one argument?? without being a string?

Comment: By it being a ... tuple :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html):

> A pair (host, port) is used for the AF_INET address family, where host is a string representing either a hostname in Internet domain notation like 'daring.cwi.nl' or an IPv4 address like '100.50.200.5', and port is an integer.

So, assuming your `ip` variable is the IP address like '100.50.200.5', and `i` is an integer with the port number, your connection code should look like

```
result = connection.connect_ex((ip, i))
```

However, it looks like your loop interates over the port_list variable, which is a string. To make it work, you would need to convert this string (e.g. "22, 23") to a list of integers ([22, 23]).

For example, you could rewrite your code like this:

```
##Print port menu
print "-"*60
print "Specify ports"
print "-"*60
print """
1)Use default list
2)Specify your own port list\n"""
print"-"*60
menu2=raw_input("Please choose an option\n")
##Define default port list
default_list="21, 22,23, 24, 25, 80, 110, 135, 139, 443, 445, 553, 3306, 3389, 8080"

##Set port list to default if option "1" is chosen
if menu2 == "1":
    port_list = default_list

##Request user port list if option "2" is chosen
if menu2 == "2":
    port_list = raw_input("Please enter the ports you would like scanned.\neg. 22, 23\n")

print "Ok, here we go"

port_list = [int(port.strip()) for port in port_list.split(',')]

for port in port_list:
    connection = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    results = connection.connect_ex((ip, port))
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess instead of

```
# abbreviated 
default_list = "21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 80, 110, 135, 139"
...
if menu2 == "1":
    port_list='default_list'
```

you mean:

```
default_list = (21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 80, 110, 135, 139)
...
if menu2 == "1":
    port_list = default_list
```

And finally instead of looping over the characters of a string:

```
for i in str(port_list):
    # do something
```

I guess you want to iterate over the list of port numbers:

```
for port in port_list:
    # do something
```

Comment: Awesome! thank you so much for the help! I will do some more reading of the official docs before attempting any further, and then will try your suggestions. thanks again!